# Core Location Manager does not ask for authorization

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, core-location

In a simple project, I instantiate a Core Location Manager:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy =
kCLDistanceFilterNone;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    // Location Services Are Enabled
    switch([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            NSLog(@"1");
            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            NSLog(@"requested auth");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            NSLog(@"2");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            NSLog(@"3");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            NSLog(@"4");
            break;
    }
} else {
    // Location Services Disabled
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

I also have the appropriate keys in info.plist:

[image]

the log output, based on this code, is:

```
[233:5927] 1
[233:5927] requested auth
```

but i get no authorization request...

no errors and no location updates (if I implement the delegate callbacks)

Comment: Ok, so the first returns YES and the second NO. how do i change the second one?

Comment: Sorry, but you have to be more specific. I retrieve it like this:
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]

Comment: So, the status is kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined. How do I force the user to determine it ? I tried multiple times to uninstall and re-install the app...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Just a hinch: Is your `locationManager` deallocated in the mean time? How is the property defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake, added the keys in the wrong plist file (the testing one instead of the app one )